# creating image as a background in the joomla menu

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

this is the template menu I'm trying to make, [creative menu with image, taken from my wordpress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVJhi.jpg)

my index.php file

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/style.css');
$doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js', 'text/javascript');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--jdoc:include type="head" sudah include bootstrap.min.js*-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- main container -->
    <div class='container'>
    <section class="feature-image">
    <h1 class="page-title title-style">CREATIVE BLOG</h1>
    </section>
        <!-- header -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-outer">
        <a class="brand" href="#">CREATIVE</a>
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav" >
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Form</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- mid container - includes main content area and right sidebar -->
        <div class='row'>

            <!-- main content area -->
            <div class='span9'>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml" />
                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
            </div>  
            <!-- right sidebar -->
            <div class='span3'>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="well" />
            </div>    
        </div>

        <!-- footer -->
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='span12'>Footer</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and below is the style.css file

```
    .main_container {
    width:940px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
    .mid_container {
        margin:20px 0px;
    }
    .main_content_area {
        float:left;
        width:700px;
    }
    .right_sidebar {
        float:right;
        width: 220px;
    }
    .main_content_area,
    .right_sidebar,
    .footer,
    .header {
        border:1px solid #bbb;
    }

    .navbar-outer
    {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .navbar-inner
    {
         list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: right;
        overflow: visible;
        border:none !important;
        background:transparent; 
    }

     .nav >li >a:hover{
        color:#5F5F5F !important; 
    }

    .mostread,
    .weblinks,
    .category-module,
    .syndicate-module,
    ul.nav.menu
    {
        margin: 100px 0px 0px 15px;
    }

    .feature-image {

    background-size: cover !important;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    display:table;
    width:100%;

    }

    h1.page-title {
    background: url("/templates/basicjoomla3.0template/images/raindrops.jpg");
    display: table-cell;
    background-size:cover;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    }
```

and its still not working, I admit I'm still a novice in joomla and web programming. The template above was created by following  a basic tutorial and I think I need to tinker with the modules provided to get the the header to look like I wanted. but I'm just not sure where to start. looking for some pointers from anyone, which would be great.

In the meantime I guess I read joomla documentation again and practice what I can

Both sites are hosted locally

Comment: A link to the Joomla website might help if this is publicly available.

Comment: @Neil it's hosted locally.

Comment: Hope this will help a bit - i rebuild your code a bit. add position absolute to your navigation bar.
http://codepen.io/arek_szczerba/pen/VPPYLG 
To make menu works i suggest to use joomla menu module.